# Is it possible to write HTML code before IF inline condition for a blade template like this?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the following piece of code

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link {{ $status === config('constants.hr.status.sent-for-approval.label') ? 'active bg-info text-white' : 'text-info' }}
    href= /{{ Request::path() . '?status=' . config('constants.hr.status.sent-for-approval.label') request()->has('search)? . 'search=' . request('search'): ''}}
```

it gives an error `syntax error, unexpected '.'` 
how can I add html code with in if condition as it is expecting a condition after `request()->has('search)?` but I'm giving `. 'search=' .` before giving condition.

Does someone have any idea that how can I implement this code?
I want to append `search=` only if the condition is true.

Comment: You might find it more readable to create a blade component if you are using Laravel 5.6, {{ sprintf('<a class="nav-item nav-link %s" href="%s?status=%s%s">example</a>',
    $status === config('constants.hr.status.sent-for-approval.label') ? 'active bg-info text-white' : 'text-info',
    Request::path(),
    config('constants.hr.status.sent-for-approval.label'),
    request()->has('search') ? '&search=' . request('search') : ""
) }}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `?` condition, but you have to add a `.` in front of it to add it to the rest of the string

```
{{ Request::path() . '?status=' . config('constants.hr.status.sent-for-approval.label') . (request()->has('search') ? . 'search=' . request('search') : '') }}
```

Also, you are missing a `'` in your `request()->has('search)`.

Comment: The real code is like  _request()->has('search')? . '&search=' . request('search') : " "_  the  **?**  represent **if the condition is true** and I have to append  **&search=** only if the condition if true. I just want to append **&search=** within IF inline statement.